# .htaccess Redirection for Querystrings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have an old website that URLs were like `/page.aspx?sch=XXXX&prg=YYYY`. I want to redirect those old URLs to my new website's URLs. I'm trying to use an .htaccess file to do the trick but I couldn't get it work. What I want is:

```
/page.aspx?sch=XXXX&prg=YYYY ==> /page/sch/XXXX/prg/YYYY
```

If someone could helped me, I'd be very pleased.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only these two URL parameters and they are only used in this order, you can do the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sch=([^&]+)&prg=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^page\.aspx$ /page/sch/%1/prg/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Otherwise you will need to extract these parameters one by one and put them in in right order before doing that redirect.